# When toggling a class on a menu element. How can I make it so that class gets removed on previously toggled elements?

Tags: javascript, class

I have this menu with different submenu's which are just `<ul>`. When clicking on a submenu the .active class will get toggled and the submenu will display. However when I click on a different submenu the desired behaviour is that the .active class will be removed from the previous submenu and applied to the new one. However what obviously happens now is that the new submenu will also get the .active class and both menu's will be open at the same time which is not what I'm after.

What would be a simple way to make sure the .active class gets removed when I click the next menu item?

This is my current code

```
$(".menu nav ul li > ul.subnav li").on("click", function (_event) {
  $(this).children("ul.subnav").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: If you were just _adding_ the class, then you could simply remove it from _all_ elements first - but if you actually want to _toggle_ it, you can't do that. So select the element that currently _has_ the class, and remove it from that one, _before_ you toggle it on the currently clicked item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove .active from the other active elements and add it for this element.

```js
$(".menu nav ul li > ul.subnav li").on("click", function (_event) {
  $(".menu nav ul li > ul.subnav li ul.subnav.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).children("ul.subnav").addClass("active");
});
```